# Undeclared identifier .WorkSheets OLE Excel

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a problem with delphi and excel ole automation. Use this code:

```
uses
ComObj
var
XlApp: Variant;
begin
L_v.Caption: = 'D:\bd1\support\Vi.xls';
XlApp: = CreateOleObject ('Excel.Application');
XLApp.Visible: = True;
XLApp.WorkBooks.Open (L_vi.Caption);
XLApp.Workbooks [1]. Worksheets. [1] Name: = 'Sheet1';
Sheets: = XLApp.Workbooks [1]. Worksheets ['test'];
```

but I get an error
undeclared identifier 'Worksheets' at line .....

I do not understand why.

Comment: This code makes early bound COM look like a good option.

Answer (score 2):

(See my edit below, marked **Updated:**.)

If this is your actual code

```
XLApp.Workbooks [1]. Worksheets. [1] Name: = 'Sheet1';
```

you have a syntax error with `Worksheets.[1]Name`. (The `.` is in the wrong place.) It should be

```
XLApp.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1].Name := 'Sheet1';
```

This works fine for me in XE3:

```
var
  XLApp: OleVariant;
begin
  XLApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  XLApp.Visible := True;
  XLApp.Workbooks.Open('C:\Test\Test.xls');
  XLApp.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1].Name := 'New Sheet Name';
end;
```

**Updated:** After your comments, I think I understand what the problem might be that you're having.

I think `Error Insight` is what's confusing you here (the red underlines and "undefined identifier" popups, which are actually wrong).

The code I posted here was compiled and actually executed in XE3 before I posted it here, and it works. But if I put the cursor over `Worksheets`, I see the `Undeclared identifier` popup and the red underline. Of course, it's correct in one way - `Worksheets` was *not* declared. It doesn't have to be, though, when you're using late binding (using `CreateOleObject` at runtime).

`Error Insight` is buggy (and has been since it was added to the IDE). The first thing I do (when I see the bug hasn't been fixed) is turn it off (Tools->Options->Editor Options->Code Insight, uncheck `Error Insight` on the right side). Let the real compiler figure things out instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made the corrections that you told me but I have always the same problem. I can write in a cell with ex.cells [1,1]: = 'test';, but worksheets and names are highlighted in red and give the error.

To me, however, does not affect rename a sheet ... I have a xls file with 50 sheets: I need to select a sheet (eg 1 or 49), but I can not ...

thanks

Comment: I compiled and ran this exact code in XE3 before I posted it. It works. If it doesn't work for you, you're using different code somehow that I can't see from here. The workbook I used has three worksheets, and I can access each of them just fine. When you say "underlined in red", that doesn't mean anything (that can just be a bug in Error Insight, which is well known - it's only visual and means nothing). Does the code compile? If it does, what happens when you run it? Do you get an exception? If so, what is the **exact** error message you get?

Comment: The error is: undeclared identifier 'Worksheets' at line .... if I have no compile error. Strange ....
But if I write --- Sheets: = Ex.Workbooks [1]. Worksheets ['sheet2']; --- the Sheet2 is selected and remains on sheet1.
This is the code I use
try
  Sheets: = Ex.Workbooks [1]. Worksheets ['ISP .. 13'];
  except
     on E: Exception do
       begin
         MessageDlg ('Error woorksheets.', MtError, [mbOK], 0);
         exit;
       end;

Comment: That's a different question than what you asked here. Your question here wasn't about selecting different worksheets. It was about undeclared identifiers. If you now have a different question, you should post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
Var 
Sheet: Olevariant;
...
   for possheet := 1 to newWorkbook.Worksheets.Count do
   Begin
        Sheet:=newWorkbook.Sheets[possheet];
        combobox1.Items.Add(Sheet.Name)
   End;
```

Comment: Pls add more information to your answer. Why to try this? What it does? What will change?

Answer (score 0):

Working with excel in delphi by this way is a bit hard because you can not clearly see the suggestions.

I'll paste some of the codes I have with `Variant` and `Excel` so you can use it.

```
uses
System.Win.ComObj, Excel2010
...

procedure GerarExcel(ADBGrid: TDBGrid; AQuery: TFDQuery);
var
  Excel: Variant;
  linha, coluna, I, X: Integer;
begin
  {Here you create the Excel Application Object}
  Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  {If you want to open the excel you can set this line to True.
  In case you want to save directly without user intervention you can set to False.}
  Excel.Visible :=True;
  Excel.Workbooks.Add;

  {In this case
  Titles begin on the (4) line and different columns (1-7)}
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,1].Interior.ColorIndex := 55;
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,1].Font.ColorIndex := 2;
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,1].Font.Bold := True;
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,1].font.size := 10;
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,1] := 'Your Title 2';
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,1].ColumnWidth := 15;
  
  ...

  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,7].Interior.ColorIndex := 55;
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,7].Font.ColorIndex := 2;
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,7].Font.Bold := True;
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,7].font.size := 10;
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,7] := 'Your Title 7';
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,7].ColumnWidth := 17;
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,7].HorizontalAlignment := 4;
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[4,7].verticalAlignment   := 1;

  I := 1;
  {In case you want to loop through a TClientDateSet to fill in the cells}
  with AQuery do
  begin
    First;
    while not Eof do
    begin
      {To change to a specific format}
      Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[I + 4, 1].NumberFormat := 'dd/mm/aaaa';
      Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[I + 4, 1] := FieldByName(C_DATA).AsDateTime;
      Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[I + 4, 2] := FieldByName(C_CONTA_CREDITO).AsString;
      Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[I + 4, 3] := FieldByName(C_CONTA_DEBITO).AsString;
      Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[I + 4, 4].NumberFormat := 'R$#.##0,00';
      Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[I + 4, 4] := FieldByName(C_VALOR).AsString;
      Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[I + 4, 5] := FieldByName(C_DESCRICAO).AsString;
      Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[I + 4, 6] := FieldByName(C_NOME).AsString;
      Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[I + 4, 7] := FieldByName(C_NOME_MOVIMENTO).AsString;
      Inc(I);

      Next;
    end;
  end;

  {All these variables configure the for landscape printing.}
  Excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter := 'Página &P de &N';
  Excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter := '&D';
  Excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation := 2;
  Excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize := xlPaperA4;
  Excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall := False;
  Excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom := False;
  Excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide := 1;

  {If you want the user to see the excel being opened and save it wherever the user wants
  You are done here.}

  {Save the file automatically
  If you want the user to NOT see the excel being opened and save the file in a specific folder automatically
  In the beginning you need to set Visible := False and then these lines}
  FilePath := 'C:\...\my_excel_file.xlsx';
  if FileExists(FilePath) then
    DeleteFile(FilePath);
  Excel.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].SaveAs(FilePath);

  Excel.Quit;
end;
```

In the [VBA API Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.saveas) you can find more.